# Connection between real android device and emulator

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-emulator, port

This question has been asked quite a few times here , but there is no good answer yet.So I am just posting this question along with my progress. I would like to know if there is a way to perform socket programming between a real device and emulator.

I referred to android developer page : http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

to establish communication between two android devices / and also between two emulators. But there is no way I am able to send data from android device(client) to emulator(as the server). Both of them are connected to the same network and are able to ping each other.

```
public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;
private Button Start;
private Button Mark;
private Button Stop;
// DEFAULT IP
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// DESIGNATE A PORT
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    Mark = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mark);
    Stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);


    //SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();


}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP +" "+ SERVERPORT);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                    final Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END
                                    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE

                                     Log.d("ServerActivity", "S: Sending command.");
                                     PrintWriter out;
                                    try {
                                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
                                         // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                                        out.println("HeyClient!");
                                        Log.d("ServerActivity", "S: Sent.");

                                        Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                //send click command to start recording to client

                                            }
                                        });

                                        } 
                                    catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// GETS THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PHONE'S NETWORK
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}}
```

and the client code :

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

```
private EditText serverIp;

private TextView serverCommand;

private Button connectPhones;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    serverCommand = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.server_commands);

}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 80);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) 
            {
                try {
                    String line = null;
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                         Log.d("ClientActivity", line);
                         serverCommand.setText(line);

                         if (line == "start")
                         {



                         }
                     }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also set up port forwarding to direct incoming connections from android at port 80 to emulator at port 6000. This is was done using telnet.

For some reason, all this doesn't seem to make emulator connect to the incoming connections.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out.

Credits : Code from http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/